# Collapsing sidebar smoothly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I created a sidebar which collapse when the screen become to small. A button then appears to open/close it. I used a transition to hide/show the sidebar in a nice way.

The sidebars `<div>` is hiding with the effect but the content of the sidebar just disappears without any effect. When I look closely on the opening behaviour, I can see the menu appearing first at full then the sidebar appearing with its effect. I want the effect on the menu content too.

Everything is in layout. css and a little code is in layout.js

Demo: *removed*

Desired effect: http://detail.herokuapp.com/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `transition: left .3s ease;` to #sidebar-nav.

I recommend you to read http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-sliding-menu/

Comment: Many Thanks ! You all solved my 2 days nightmare withing one hour !
You're gods, keep going !

Answer (score 3):

Add transition to sidebar-nav that's it !

```
#sidebar-nav{
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;// I am adding webkit please add the rest yourself.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack order of your sidebar is above the content. You can change that with changing:

```
#sidebar-nav {
z-index:0;
}
```